# Convert Batch File to Run remotely via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following batch file:

```
type nul>"\\gccevault\f$\EVDATA\Archives\VSG01\MailboxVS01\Ptn1\ignorearchivebittrigger.txt"

REM clear backup mode on site "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -psconsolefile "f:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVShell.psc1" -command "& {clear-VaultStoreBackupMode -Name GCC -EVServerName gccevault1 -EVObjectType Site}"

REM clear backup mode on indexes in site
"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -psconsolefile "f:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVShell.psc1" -command "& {clear-IndexLocationBackupMode -EVServerName gccevault1 -EVSiteName GCC}"
```

I need to convert it to be able to execute it on the computer its on, but call it from a different server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use PowerShell remoting to invoke a batch file remoting like this

Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer { & {c:\temp\localfile.bat} }